# Inserting blank rows into an asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a stored procedure that brings back a record set that binds to an ASP:GridView. If the procedure can't find data that should be displayed and returns no records, I want blank rows inserted into the ASP GridView so that I can access the rows for assigning row header labels. This grid should have a **static** number of rows and each contains BoundFields and TemplateFields. What is required to insert these empty rows?

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="myGrid_rowBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
      <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblRowHeader" runat="server"</asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="AsOf" DataFormatString="{0:F1}" />
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <input type="text" ID="txtToHire" />
                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtToHire" Display="None" />
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Current" DataFormatString="{0:F1}" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Guideline" DataFormatString="{0:F1}" />
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
// normal stored procedure call and binding
// ....

DataTable newSource = new DataTable();
if (myGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = newSource.NewRow();
        newSource.Rows.InsertAt(dr, i);
    }

    myGrid.DataSource = newSource;
    myGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why not create a DataTable, List, or other object with a fixed set of empty rows and Bind it to the grid if the stored proc returns no rows? If named identically to the columns returned from the stored proc dataset, it should bind normally.

Comment: I agree with @DeveloperDad.  Additionally, if you need a fixed number of rows and your data source returns data, but less than the required number of rows, it is easy to create blank rows to add to the DataTable (or list), then bind it.

Comment: "If named identically". That's the real part I'm struggling with. What property should be set for this? I'm looping and doing this...

DataRow dr = newSource.NewRow();
newSource.Rows.InsertAt(dr, i);

Comment: @GregVanGorp possible put your code behind.

Comment: I've seen something like this with an empty edit row at either the top or the bottom...is that what you need? You'd add those into the footer...

Answer (score 0):

The reason the rows weren't binding to the GridView was not because the rows didn't have the right column name set, it was because I didn't add the columns *to the DataTable*. This code was what I was missing:

```
DataTable newSource = new DataTable();

newSource.Columns.Add("AsOf");
newSource.Columns.Add("Current");
newSource.Columns.Add("Guideline");

// Now programatically add the rows that I needed
```